# Haskell show data

Tags: haskell, instance, show

```
data Months = January|February|March|April|May|June|July
         deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)
instance Show Months where 

show January="Jan"
show February="Feb"
show March="Mar"
....
```

What do I need to do to show the output as such: ”Jan”, ”Feb”, ..., ”July" ?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking - do you need help with your `Show` instance - it is wrongly indented use at least 2 spaces before  each `show ...`; if you mean how to print it on command line - use `print January` or `putStrLn $ show January`

Comment: I would also call your datatype `Month` - as the plural would usually indicate a list of things (this is just convention).

Answer (score 1):

`Show` can be derived automatically:

```
data Months = January | February | March | April | May | June | July
              deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show)
```

And so:

```
λ> show January 
"January"
```

I suppose there might be a good reason that you want your `Show` instance to display those abbreviated month names, but why not just change the names of your data constructors to match?

Comment: instead of show January, can I have it so that when I write show Months, they are all displayed? @mdunsmuir

Comment: @benjy1911 Use `show [January .. July]`. The `Enum` instance allows you to generate all of the months in sequence.

Comment: Or, better yet, derive also `Bounded` and `show [minBound .. maxBound]` , just in case more months are added later.